# Get Values from a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a UI on flutter using some dummy data. I have modelled a class named movies

```
class Movies {
  final String movieName;
  final int rating;
  final String imgUrl;
  final String desc;
  final String runTime;
  final String language;
  final List<String> genre;

  Movies(
      {this.movieName,
      this.rating,
      this.imgUrl,
      this.desc,
      this.runTime,
      this.language,
      this.genre});
}
```

And Created a list of data

```
List<Movies> movielists = [
  Movies(
    movieName: 'Karnan',
    language: 'Tamil',
    rating: 3,
    imgUrl:
        'https://www.filmibeat.com/ph-big/2021/04/karnan-movie-posters_16179793174.jpg',
    desc:
        'Karnan, a fearless village youth, must fight for the rights of the people of his village. The people of the village belong to a marginalized community that has been oppressed for decades, mainly by the dominant caste groups in the region aided by the government officials and the police who intend to keep them suppressed under their shoes',
    runTime: '143.2',
    genre: ['Thriller', 'Crime'],
  ),
  Movies(
    movieName: 'Wrath Of Man',
    language: 'English',
    rating: 4,
    imgUrl:
        'https://cdn.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Wrath-of-Man.jpg',
    desc:
        'Patrick Hill begins work at Fortico Security, an armored truck company. After being commended by the superior Terry for his references, he is introduced to Bullet, who nicknames him "H" and oversees his training. H gets off to a rocky start with his colleagues, particularly Boy Sweat Dave, over his mysterious nature',
    runTime: '94.8',
    genre: ['Action', 'Thriller'],
  ),
  Movies(
    movieName: 'GodZilla vs Kong',
    language: 'English',
    rating: 5,
    imgUrl:
        'https://cdn.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Godzilla-vs-Kong-Dolby-600x889.jpg',
    desc:
        'Five years after Godzilla defeated King Ghidorah,[c] Kong is monitored by Monarch within a giant dome on Skull Island. Kong is visited by Jia, the last Iwi native and Kong expert Ilene Andrews',
    runTime: '94.8',
    genre: ['Action', 'Thriller'],
  ),
];
```

How Can I Access this data? I'm still learning flutter, pointing out what I'm missing will be helpful

Comment: Did you try movielists[0] ? Or if you want get movie name movielists[0].movieName ?

Comment: yes. by using movielists[0] i'm getting the first value. But how can i get all the data from list ? My objective is to create a listview,using the length of these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, you should add **"require"** in your class. Otherwise dart will give you a similar error like the next one:

> line 51 • The parameter 'movieName' can't have a value of 'null'
> because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (view
> docs) Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the
> 'required' modifier.

2. Import the class and the example information where you need it.

   import 'package:exampleapp/movie_list_sample_information.dart;

   import 'package:exampleapp/movies.dart;
3. Use the variable to get the information

   movieLists[0].movieName // gets the first movie of your list

The next dartpad uses your code as example: https://dartpad.dev/95d67aa68267296ac3fd8a56405b2880?null_safety=true

Press "Run" button and you should see the name of the first movie in "Console"

[image]

**EDIT:**

To read the list in dynamically in flutter you can use ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: movieLists.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final Movies movies = movieLists[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('${movies.movieName}'),
            );
          },
        );
```

New Dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/flutter?null_safety=true&id=833b53af6b75b64d751381092dbe07ed

[image: ListView.builder]

Comment: By using movielists[0] i'm getting the first value. But how can i get all the data from list ? My objective is to create a listview,using the length of these data.

Comment: @FebinJohnson then you need to use a ListView.Builder

For example: https://dartpad.dev/flutter?null_safety=true&id=833b53af6b75b64d751381092dbe07ed